# Score move to otherscene from skscene

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, sprite-kit

I can't receive score in other scene. I setup @propery but it doesn't works. Score is "0" every time it not change.
My codes here.

OtherScene.h

```
@interface OtherScene : SKScene
@propery NSUInteger score;
@end
```

OtherScene.m

```
@implementation OtherScene
{
SKLabelNode *scoreLabel;
}

-(void)addScoreLabel
{
scoreLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];
scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SCORE: %lu", (unsigned long)self.score];
scoreLabel.position = CGPointMake(500, 50);
scoreLabel.name = @"gameOverScore";
[self addChild:scoreLabel];
}
```

MyScene.m

```
@interface MyScene ()<SKPhysicsContactDelegate>
@property NSUInteger score;
@end
- (void)gameOver
{

GameOverScene *gameOverScene = [GameOverScene sceneWithSize:self.size];
gameOverScene.score = self.score;
[self.view presentScene:gameOverScene transition:[SKTransition pushWithDirection:SKTransitionDirectionLeft duration:0.5]];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When/where do you call addScoreLabel?

If this is in OtherScene init you're effectively running it in the line

```
GameOverScene *gameOverScene = [GameOverScene sceneWithSize:self.size];
```

Meaning: *before* you assigned the score. You could simply call the update label method from MyScene after assigning the score:

```
GameOverScene *gameOverScene = [GameOverScene sceneWithSize:self.size];
gameOverScene.score = self.score;
[gameOverScene addScoreLabel];
```

Or even better, do this in a custom property setter method in OtherScene, ie `setScore:(NSUInteger)score` and separate creating the label from updating its score string to be more flexible.

Comment: how can i set [gameOverScene addScoreLabel]; for used in MyScene